# Color tag in Finder on NFS share

Tags: nfs, finder

I want a group of OS X users to be able to color tag each others' files in a NFS shared directory. The NFS share is hosted on a Solaris machine.

Currently the files have `rwx` group permissions but only the owner may set color tags.
It's first when the owner has set a tag that others are allowed to set additional tags on the same file.

Is there any additional permission or ACL that can enable this?